# "Constructor cannot be applied to given types" when constructors have inheritance

Tags: java, constructor

This is my base class:

```
abstract public class CPU extends GameObject {
    protected float shiftX;
    protected float shiftY;

    public CPU(float x, float y) {
        super(x, y);
    }
```

and here is one of its subclasses:

```
public class Beam extends CPU {
    public Beam(float x, float y, float shiftX, float shiftY, int beamMode) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/tab/Pictures/Beam"+beamMode+".gif"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.shiftX = shiftX;
        this.shiftY = shiftY;
    }
```

The New constructor is highlighted and it says:

```
Constructor CPU in class CPU cannot be applied to given types:
required: float, float
found: no arguments
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 17):

As the error is trying to tell you, you need to pass parameters to your base class' constructor.

Add `super(x, y);`

Answer (score 4):

The final object needs to in initialize the super class using one of its constructors. If there is a default (no-parameter) constructor then the compiler calls it implicitly, otherwise the subclass constructor needs to call it using `super` as the first line of its constructor.

In your case, that would be:

```
public Beam(float x, float y, float shiftX, float shiftY, int beamMode) { 
  super(x, y)
```

And remove the assignments to `this.x` and `this.y` later.

Also, avoid making them `protected`, makes it difficult to debug. Instead add `getters` and if absolutely necessary `setters`

Comment: From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html: You don't have to provide any constructors for your class, but you must be careful when doing this. The compiler automatically provides a no-argument, default constructor for any class without constructors. This default constructor will call the no-argument constructor of the superclass. In this situation, the compiler will complain if the superclass doesn't have a no-argument constructor so you must verify that it does.

Comment: And from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html: Note: If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you should write

```
protected float shiftX;
protected float shiftY;

public CPU(float x, float y, float shiftX, float shiftY) {
    super(x, y);
    this.shiftX = shiftX;
    this.shiftY = shiftY
}
```

and

```
public Beam(float x, float y, float shiftX, float shiftY, int beamMode) {
    super(x,y,shiftX,shiftY);
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("/home/tab/Pictures/Beam"+beamMode+".gif"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify any default constructor then at the compile time it will give you this error "constructor in class cannot be applied to given type;" 
Note: If you created any parameterized constructor.