# How to access superclass variables from user input

Tags: java

I am trying to access the super class variable name from user input.
I am not sure how to have the super class variable name point to the user input. Here is the code for it. Any ideas thank you.

```
    package chapter4;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class VetOffice extends Animal {

        public VetOffice(int lifeExpectancy, int weight, String name, Character gender, String type) {
            super(lifeExpectancy, weight, name, gender, type);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
       public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

                System.out.print("Please enter name of pet");
                //super(name);
                //= console.next();
        //}
        }   
    }
    //}
```

Comment: it may be helpful if you can share the `Animal` super class.

Comment: `VetOffice` **inherits** the property(fields and methods) of its superclass `Animal`. So, if there are `getters` & `setters` methods in the superclass, you can use them in the subclass.

Comment: `VetOffice` extends `Animal`???   That's a red flag right there...

Answer (score 0):

The thing is you cannot access super class variables in `main` method. Because it is `static` method. If you want to access in `main()` you have to make `Animal` class `name` variable to static. Then you can assgin a value directly in `main()`.

Like this:

in Animal class,

```
static String name;
```

in VetOffice,

```
name = console.next();
```

You can try different ways depending on the thing that you are going to achieve you have to decide,

Is this variable can be declare as `static` or not? Because `static` variables common for every object.

Another way you can do this is,

Create getters and setters for `Animal` class member variables. Then also you cannot access in the main method because also you have to make those methods and variable to static.

As a solution without makinng them static or a new methods even getters and setters in super class you can create default constructor for super class and assign values like below:

If your variable in the super class is `private` you have to create getters and setters.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Please enter name of pet");

   VetOffice pet = new VetOffice();
   pet.name = console.next();
   System.out.println(pet.name);
}
```

**Note:** create default constructor If it is unnecessary to create object from `VetOffice` or super class seeing that you have to pass values to constructor.

**UPDATE:**

According to your comment

If your variable in the super class is `private` do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.print("Please enter name of pet");

   VetOffice pet = new VetOffice();
   pet.setName(console.next());
   System.out.println(pet.getName());
}
```

Another way that you asked for in the comment:

Animal class(partialy implemented to show you)

```
public class Animal {
    int lifeExpectancy;
    static int weight;
    static String name;

    Animal(int lifeExpectancy, int weight, String name, Character gender, String type){
        this.weight = weight;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public static void setName(String n) {
        name = n;
    }
}
```

Then in the main method:

```
Animal.setName(console.next());
System.out.println(Animal.getName());
```

Comment: I have getter and setters in the animal class. So how do i create a VetOffice object. How do I call the setName() in VetOffice.

Comment: Ok I understand that but why would I not call the variable super to access the variable name from the super class.

Comment: @Derrick C `super()` is not a variable. Read this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134360/inheritance-with-constructor-in-java/44135109#44135109

Comment: I tried that but it says to create a VetOffice constructor and when I did that it said. Implicit super constructor animal is undefined must explicitly invoke another constructor. Is there a way I can use setName with the superclass. ie Animal.setName or super(setName).

Comment: if you want `super(setName)` this has to be in constructor

Comment: As I said before `Animal.setName` you can do like that if you make setters, getters and `name` variable to static

Comment: @Derrick C I updated the answer. Look at the bottom of answer in update section.

Comment: I did that but I get a null value  returned when I execute          System.out.println(Animal.getName());

Comment: @DerricC Change `setName(String n)` and `name = n;`

Comment: ok it is working thank you. How can I get a hold of you for future questions?

Comment: I think there is no way for that but you can mention me in your question comments - @Blasanka